# What is my indentation style called. Is there an emacs style for it?

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style

I tend to write code like:

```
void myfunc()
{
}

if (statement){
    dostuff();
} 
else{
    dootherstuff();
}

switch (var){
    case 1: 
    {
        stuff();
    }
    break;

    case 2:
        stuff();
        break;
};
```

Is there a formatting mode for this? what's it called?

If not, or there is one that is close to it, how do I modify my `.emacs` file to make it indent correctly?

Comment: Based on braces, I'd call that "inconsistent." :P It's similar in some manners to the linux kernel style guide, perhaps.

Comment: Why vote to close, it's on topic according to the faq?

Comment: It is called "Bad style": Code outside functions, magic number 2 as case label, switch does not have default but has pointless ; after } of its block. Also names like 'dootherstuff' are not easy to read.

Comment: false positive closes happen sometime.

Comment: @Öö Tiib It is *sample* of different constructs. Question should be stated as "what is my intent style". It is not related to content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [K&R style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).